# Efficient way to calculate pandas columns with pymap3d?

Tags: python, pandas, geo

I have a pandas dataframe with columns of geo-coordinates and I am using pymap3d to convert the locations to other coordinate systems. A typical function I have implemented to do this is:

```
def append_enu(df, observerlla):
e = []
n = []
u = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    tmpe, tmpn, tmpu = pm.geodetic2enu( row["lat_deg"], row["lon_deg"], row["alt_m"], *observerlla )
    e.append(tmpe)
    n.append(tmpn)
    u.append(tmpu)
df["enu_e_m"] = e
df["enu_n_m"] = n
df["enu_u_m"] = u
return df
```

This works, but I find it **extremely slow**. (My tables have over 700000 rows, and I am adding conversions for 3 different coordinate systems.) Is there a "more pythonic" way to do this that properly takes advantage of the ways pandas allows dataframe manipulation?

Comment: Sounds like [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) might be what you are looking for. It can quickly apply a function across a column or row of any numpy/pandas array

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I came up with, which modifies the original DataFrame instead of returning a new one from a function:

```
(df['enu_e_m'], df['enu_n_m'], df['enu_u_m']) = pm.geodetic2enu(df['lat_deg'], df['lon_deg'], df['alt_m'], *observerlla)
```

So, yeah, "it just works."